# Grabbing SurfaceTexture's GL context from NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, opengl-es-2.0

**Purpose :** 
I'm using `SurfaceTexture` for displaying the camera preview, and need to draw on top of surface by acquiring GL context from NDK. I've chosen `SurfaceTexture` approach as I can avoid camera frame buffer's manual passing from java to NDK, to save some performance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceTextureListener {

private Camera mCamera;
private TextureView mTextureView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mTextureView = new TextureView(this);
    mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

    setContentView(mTextureView);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    Camera.Size previewSize = mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    mTextureView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(previewSize.width, previewSize.height, Gravity.CENTER));

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewTexture(surface);
    } catch (IOException t) {
    }

    mCamera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
    // Ignored, the Camera does all the work for us
}

@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    // Update your view here
}
```

**What I've tried :**
I suppose `SurfaceTexture` internally uses GL functionality for drawing the context. From NDK getting the default display fails with `BAD_DISPLAY` error.

```
EGLDisplay display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
```

Of course I'm able to initialize a new GL context and do my drawing but still I want to keep the texture displayed from java code in background.

**Question :** Is it possible at all to grab the GL context from NDK when using `SurfaceTexture` ? 
Probably I have to use on `GLSurfaceView`, initialize GL context manually from java code and grab it from NDK ?

Comment: have you seen the Roman Guy's [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/U5RXFGpAHPE/IqHeIeGXhr0J) about working with TextureView and getting hold of EGL context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question doesn't entirely make sense to me, so let me set out a few things.

- SurfaceTexture does not draw anything.  When Camera is connected as a producer, SurfaceTexture receives a YUV frame, and uses EGL functions to set it up as an "external" texture.  You can then render that texture with GLES.
- EGL contexts can be "current" in one thread at a time.  The pointer to the current context is kept in native thread-local storage.  The Java-language GLES bindings are a thin wrapper around native code, so there's little conceptual difference between Java and C++ when working with GLES.
- The SurfaceTexture's texture will be associated with whichever context was current when the object was created, but you can switch it to a different context using the attach/detach calls.  You can't "grab" the SurfaceTexture's EGL context, but you can tell it which one you want it to use.
- SurfaceTexture (and Surface in general) can only have one producer.  You can't send Camera frames to a Surface that you're rendering onto with GLES.  You can switch back and forth between them, but it's usually better to use two different Surface objects.
- A TextureView is a View with an embedded SurfaceTexture.  When asked to redraw, it uses GLES to render from the texture (which is why you don't see anything at all if you disable hardware rendering).

If I'm understanding your question correctly, I think what you want to do is:

- Send the Camera output to a new SurfaceTexture created on the renderer thread.
- Create an EGLSurface for the TextureView's SurfaceTexture.
- Render onto the TextureView with GLES, using the texture from the Camera as the sample source.  Add in whatever other GLES rendering you want.

Various examples can be found in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), e.g. the "texture from camera" Activity.

Comment: Thanks for clarification on internals !